# Are items in ME3 multiplayer shared across characters?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I would like to know if the items you unlock when purchasing a package can be shared between the different characters you created, or if they are limited to the first characters that use them.

I'm asking that since I just got a pistol mod, that I used on my sentinel, and then playing with my vanguard, I wasn't able to access the mod.

Is that normal, or is there something to do?
 (rather than buy a new pack :D)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Items are shared across all your characters.  If you unlock a weapon or mod in a weapon pack, you can add them to all your multiplayer characters.